# ValueError - The Hydrant could not be created because the data didn't validate

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to use a ModelForm to create and save an object to my database, but I keep getting a ValueError telling me my data isn't validated once I submit the POST data.

This is in models.py

```
class Hydrant(models.Model):
    gpscoord = models.OneToOneField(GPSCoord)
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address)
    size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '(' + str(self.gpscoord.latitude) + ', ' + str(self.gpscoord.longitude) + ')'

class HydrantForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hydrant
```

This is in views.py

```
def hydrant_create(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HydrantForm(request.POST)
        new_hydrant = form.save() #it breaks here
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('hydrant_detail', args=(new_hydrant.id,)))
    else:
        form = HydrantForm() #unbound form

    return render(request, 'structures/hydrant_create.html', {'form': form})
```

This is hydrant_create.html

```
<h3> Creating Hydrant</h3>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'hydrant_create' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

{{ form.as_p }}

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

At 'structures/hydrants/create', my html template looks fine (although I can only select GPSCoord and Address objects that have already be created -- is there an easy fix for this?).  Once I enter in the data on the form and click submit, however, I get this:

## ValueError at /structures/hydrants/create/

### The Hydrant could not be created because the data didn't validate.

I trawled through StackOverflow, but the major issue other people were having was separating the creation of a new object and the modification of an existing object (I have two views to handle this, and the "editing" view runs into the same problem at the same place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `form.is_valid()` before `form.save()`. This will ensure the form submitted has all the required data for your model. If the form validation fails, it will display back to your user what is wrong. [Check out the documentation for further information.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view)

```
def hydrant_create(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HydrantForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_hydrant = form.save() #it breaks here
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('hydrant_detail', args=(new_hydrant.id,)))
    else:
        form = HydrantForm() #unbound form

    return render(request, 'structures/hydrant_create.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for quick response.  I put that in, and it tells me that a Hydrant with the selected Gpscoord and the selected Address already exists.  I have a one-to-one relationship for Hydrant and these two models, but is there a way I can enable creation of a GPSCoord and an Address on the same Hydrant creation page?  I remember doing that for the admin interface using inlines.

Comment: If you need more than one gpscoord and address in your `Hydrant` table then perhaps those fields should be switched to `models.ForeignKey`?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear.  They should be one-to-one, but I'd like to enable creation of new gpscoords and new addresses on the hydrant creation view.